# How do I get the viewport meta tag to work correctly on my responsive site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I'm setting up a website www.bytework.dk.

I've added the viewport meta tag, which usually always works fine for me, so the site looks right on smartphones. But for some reason, this site ignores it completely and the site is zoomed out to full size on mobile.

I've checked all the javascript code, I've checked the CSS. I have no idea why the hell it has no function?

Whatever settings I try with the viewport meta tag it has absolutely no effect on the appearance of the page on a smartphone???

This is the code I'm using:

```
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

EDIT: Seems the problem is related to some dns settings on the domain provider I'm using and the shitty solution they made.

Comment: I tried it on 5 different browsers with a small screen size and could not replicate your issue

Comment: No you didn't cuz it doesn't work.

Comment: I absolutely did. 300px screen size. Chrome, Firefox, IE11, Safari, Opera, and Edge. Also Chrome for Android. Every single time it opened like a normal responsive webpage. What browser and device are you having issues with?

Comment: Chrome on android and every single mobile emulator chrome has to offer on windows aswell. When I open the site it's zoomed out and doesn't show the mobile menu or anything else correctly.

Comment: I'm getting a 404 error now, but I had noticed that you are loading the site in a frameset and frame, which is not compatible with HTML5. Maybe a DOCTYPE declaration can instruct the browser to use "HTML Frameset DTD" or "XHTML Frameset DTD" so it doesn't cause rendering issues.

Comment: I'm not doing anything. I just set up a http forward on my domain provider, the site is hosted on another webhost. I have no control of that part, which seems to be the main problem. Reason you're getting errors is because I tinkered with the dns settings to find another way.

Comment: I also recall that the there was no viewport meta tag on the page that hosts the frameset, which could possibly be part of the issue

Comment: I have contact the domain provider about the issue, hopefully they can do something about it.

Comment: Looks like you fixed it

Comment: Yes it was because of the forward which uses an iframe, this restricts you from controlling the viewport. Had to change the server setup.

Answer (score 0):

try to open it in an incognito window (if you're using Google Chrome) and see if that's still happening or clean up your cache, restart your browser and try again.

Comment: Sorry but if the problem was this simple I wouldn't make an entire frickin post about it.